# Set waiting time for process to exit

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file

I am using the following command to run the bat file:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "d:/my.bat";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit(2000000);               
p.Close();
p.Dispose();
```

My problem is that I need to wait until the above process get completed and close it as soon as it is possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It already does that.  That's what `WaitForExit` does.

Comment: @Servy but it does not help me i need to set maximum is it possible

Comment: Wrap that whole bit in a `using` block as `Process` implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: @GowthamanSS Then use `int.MaxValue` as the parameter argument as that's the highest possible, or omit the value to wait indefinitely.

Comment: Are you saying you need to define how long the calling process will wait for the child process to complete? And if that's the case, what should happen to the child process once the time interval elapses? Terminate?

Answer (score 5):

You can replace `p.WaitForExit(2000000)` with `p.WaitForExit();` in order to manage the case where the process takes longer than 2000000 milliseconds to run.

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: ya ur right but through my code with in process got over completely it moves through next set of code how can i solve it

Answer (score 2):

Just use `WaitForExit` without any parameter like:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "d:/my.bat";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
p.Close();
p.Dispose();
```

It will wait until your process is done. See [the documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) for more info.

Alternatively, and especially if you want to give feedback to the user, you can do something like this:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "d:/my.bat";
Console.Write("Running {0} ", p.StartInfo.FileName)
p.Start();
while (!p.HasExited)
{
    Console.Write(".");
    // wait one second
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
Console.WriteLine(" done.");
p.Close();
p.Dispose();
```

Comment: @ Yannick Blondeau ya ur right but through my code with in process got over completely it moves through next set of code how can i solve it –

Comment: I've added another way of doing it. HTH.

Comment: it is also not solving my problem

Comment: It is working as expected on my system, maybe your problem comes from what's inside your bat file. You may use the [Process.Exit Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) as a workaround...

Comment: ya in that bat file i am just running a command to take db2 database dump while on normal clicking of bat file it takes around 1 min to complete but through code i need to wait untill it get over thats where i stuck on it